# .NET array output

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, wcf

I have a probably very basic question, but I can't figure it out. (almost weekend ;P )
I have this function ReadOpenCalls(int relation) which gets the open calls from a relation.

```
List<string> messages = new List<string>();

if (inboundSet != null && inboundSet.RecordCount > 0)
{
    inboundSet.MoveFirst();

    do
    {
        messages.Add(inboundSet.Fields["DESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString());
        messages.Add(inboundSet.Fields["PK_R_INBOUNDMESSAGE"].Value.ToString());

        inboundSet.MoveNext();
    }
    while (!inboundSet.EOF);

    return messages;
}
```

It's called via WCF into a PHP page. Now that all works perfectly fine, my only problem is the output of it:

`stdClass Object ( [string] => Array ( [0] => Webservice [1] => 1004 [2] => Webservice [3] => 1005 [4] => Webservice [5] => 1006 [6] => Webservice [7] => 1007 [8] => Webservice [9] => 1008 [10] => Webservice [11] => 1009 [12] => Webservice [13] => 1010 [14] => Webservice [15] => 1011 ) )`

And I really want the output to have the "Webservice and ID's" in this case to be together and not all in one big array.

So something like

```
[0] => Webservice,
       1004
[1] => Webservice,
       1005
```

Please help me with some examples or a shot in the good direction. I will buy you a beer after ;)

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Your C# code creates a flat list and naturally that's what you can access in PHP. What is your question here? Are you asking how to change the C# code?

Comment: Yes, I really want to know how I can achieve the output I want. I'm not very experienced with .NET so any shot in the good direction is good :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling the `Add`method twice, like you do here:

```
 do
 {
    messages.Add(inboundSet.Fields["DESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString());
    messages.Add(inboundSet.Fields["PK_R_INBOUNDMESSAGE"].Value.ToString());
    inboundSet.MoveNext();
 }
```

Just call it *once* per iteration, and add *both* values.

```
 do
 {
    string desc = inboundSet.Fields["DESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString();
    string inboundMsg = inboundSet.Fields["PK_R_INBOUNDMESSAGE"].Value.ToString()
    messages.Add(desc  +", "+inboundMsg );
    inboundSet.MoveNext();
 }
```

If the linebreak is required, then do this:

```
 do
 {
    string desc = inboundSet.Fields["DESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString();
    string inboundMsg = inboundSet.Fields["PK_R_INBOUNDMESSAGE"].Value.ToString()
    messages.Add(desc  +",\n"+inboundMsg );
    inboundSet.MoveNext();
 }
```

Comment: I owe you a beer! Thank you very much, but can you please explain what you did now? You gave a name at the 2 values and then added them together? I think I get it now. :D

Comment: @Marijke you are welcome. I only added the names `desc` and `inboundMsg` to make the code "looks nice". You could just as easy do it in one line:  `messages.Add(inboundSet.Fields["DESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString()+", "+inboundSet.Fields["PK_R_INBOUNDMESSAGE"].Value.ToString());` without the variables :)

Comment: Just like I thought, nah it looks better with the names haha ;) You really saved my day AND weekend!